# Percentage of Parent Total in Google Sheets Pivot Table

Tags: google-sheets, filter, pivot-table, vlookup, percentage

I'm trying to find the percentage of the parent/category total in the below Pivot table.  I manually calculated Column E to show what data I would like the Pivot table to return.  Basically, I am looking for it to calculate the total percentage of each drink in a category based on the total number of drinks sold within that category.

Is this possible to do in Pivot Tables in Google Sheets?  I know Excel has a % of Parent Total value but it doesn't seem like that is an option in GSheets.  Is there is a custom calculated field that could be a work around for this?

[image]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Just added the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
={"Percent of Category"; INDEX(IFNA(C6:C/VLOOKUP(A6:A, 
 SUBSTITUTE(FILTER({A6:A, C6:C}, REGEXMATCH(A6:A, "Total")), " Total", ), 2, 0)))}
```

[image]